# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when Argument contains quotes

Tags: java

I am passing a UNC Path as an argument to the Jar.  Sometime that UNC path may contain space. So I tried wrapping the UNC Path in double quotes, but getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

For Example, below format is working fine for me..

```
xx.jar //someloc/someloc/ Arg2 Arg3 ..
```

But below format throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
xx.jar "//some loc/some loc/" Arg2 Arg3 ..
```

I am not sure why its throwing error when using double quotes. Is there any way pass the UNC path with spaces without quotes ? or Am i doing any mistake ?

Sample Code..

```
public class Ab
{
static String[] inputparam = new String[20];

public static void main(String[] args) {


        org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
        inputparam = args;
abc();
}
public static void abc() throws IOException, NamingException, URISyntaxException {

        String HadoopConfigPath = inputparam[0];

Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.set("fs.defaultFS", HadoopURI);
        config.addResource(new File(HadoopConfigPath + "HadoopConfigFiles\\core-site.xml").toURI().toURL());
        config.addResource(new File(HadoopConfigPath + "HadoopConfigFiles\\hdfs-site.xml").toURI().toURL());
        config.addResource(new File(HadoopConfigPath + "HadoopConfigFiles\\mapred-site.xml").toURI().toURL());
        config.addResource(new File(HadoopConfigPath + "HadoopConfigFiles\\yarn-site.xml").toURI().toURL());
```

Comment: `//some\ loc//some\ loc`

Comment: UNC paths may or maynot  contain space. I need to generalize it. It should work for both - with sapce or without space..

Comment: please, can you place the code where you process the argument?

Comment: Why cant I use quotes? Any specific reason ? @px06

Comment: I think the problem is in your code, because the command line looks right.

Comment: So, you're using `File` which accepts whitespaces in path just fine, so I'm not sure what could be wrong here but why are you not using `args` instead of `inputparam`? Also what's the type of `inputparam`?

Comment: I wish, one day you'll receive code which had `toLowerCase()` applied on it...

Comment: You can't declare a method inside another method. Add real code with [mcve]

Comment: you should trace those values, so you and we see what they actually are.

Comment: Why not just debug what's actually coming into `inputparam`? Just print the array out and see what's actually happening, because we don't have your full code to verify what the actual issue could be here.

Comment: When your backslash is quoted you don't have to escape it.

Comment: @xenteros its my wrong.. I edited the question..  I found the issue..  Its working if I give like this "xx.jar `"\\some loc\some loc\\"`  I just add the extra backslash at the end before end quotes.

Comment: @PadmanabhanVijendran does it mean that your problem is solved? If so, did my answer help?

Comment: @xenteros You just pointed out the mistake in my question. I am still wondering why do I need to give extra backslash at the end before quotes.

Comment: To escape the backslash. Backslash is a special character which says defines the next character meaning. For example `\n` means new line. If you want to have `"\"` as a literal in java you have to write `"\\" ` as it represents single backslash.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue and fixed myself.

I actually passing the UNC path with the extra backslash at the end. For example I am passing like `xx.jar "\\some loc\som loc\"` instead of `xx.jar "\\some loc\some loc"`

It didnt give any issue when we are not using double quotes if we use the backslash at the end for the UNC Path. But its throwing error when we use double quotes and backslash at the end.

To fix that, I added a extra backslash like below

`xx.jar "\\some loc\some loc\\"`

Comment: You completely ignore [so] rules. Please read [ask], [answer] and how to provide [mcve].

Comment: couriously, in your question, you don't have back- but forward slashes... also, as written now, you escape the "s" of "some", instead of having a path with a backslash in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is very low quality. You didn't provide enough information to answer it for sure but we might have some assumptions.

Let's assume that your code compiles. According to your code, `inputparameters` which should be called `inputParameters` and actually shouldn't be used as you have `args` has at least 1 element so there is no possibility to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when calling index `0`. Important thing! It's `IndexOutOfBoundsException` not ``Indexoutofboundsexception`.

And now let me explain you why your code doesn't compile and you probably run something different.

1. You can't declare a method `abc` inside of `main`. More over, you can't declare any method inside another method unless it's a `Lambda`!
2. You have to close brackets. At least two `{` are not closed!

And last but not least, you don't have to escape slashes in your OS when they are quoted... and why would you 'escape' non-back slashes?

```
xx.jar "/some loc/some loc" Arg2 Arg3 ..
```